# Can I override a property's class with a subclass of the class in my .m file?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Given that I have a Game class:

```
@interface Game : NSObject
```

with a CutthroatGame subclass:

```
@interface CutthroatGame : Game
```

If I have a property like this in my ViewController .h file:

```
@property (strong) Game *game;
```

Can I safely override the property like this in my ViewController .m file:

```
if (_playerCount == 3) {
    _game = [[CutthroatGame alloc] init];
else {
    _game = [[Game alloc] init];   
}
```

Edit: If this is supposed to work, how do I deal with the below error?

CutthroatGame defines a number of additional properties, such as:

```
@property (strong) Player *opponent2
```

When I try to access them using the _game property of my ViewController, I get the following error:

```
 _game.opponent2 = [players objectAtIndex:0]; -- ERROR: Property 'opponent2' was not found on object of type 'Game *'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! That is what [*Liskov substitution principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is about. If you properly subclass `CutthroatGame` from `Game`, you will have no problem substituting `Game` with its subclass.

Comment: Awesome, I was hoping that was the case. Thanks for the quick response and the light reading! Coming from non-object oriented languages, this is a new concept for me. Thanks again!

Comment: So.. I did find a "gotcha" on this. CutthroatGame does specify additional properties. When I try to access those properties I get an error. I will add the info/code to the question.

Comment: @AndrewRobinson Although you cannot access the additional properties through the dot notation, you can access them through the method notation. For example, `game.additional_property` will not be valid, but `[game additional_property]` will work fine, assuming that you do not access this property on the "plain" `Game` object.

Comment: Tried something like: [_game setOpponent2:[players objectAtIndex:0]]; to no avail. Also getting an error with [_game opponent2];

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Why would the bracket notation work?  If the object is of type `Game` then the compiler will only allow methods defined in the `Game` class without a cast right?

Comment: @borrrden Objective C is dynamically typed. If the compiler finds a class that responds to a message, you can send that message to any object. Of course if the object is of a wrong type, there will be a runtime error.

Comment: @AndrewRobinson Do you get a compile-time error or a runtime error? Did you include the header for the class with the additional property?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am aware that you *can* at runtime, but the compiler will only allow any message to be sent with `id` types (as opposed to this one of type `Game`).  For the compiler to allow it you have to fall back to `performSelector:`.  I just tried it out.

Comment: I think I am just going to add the additional properties to the `Game` class, and add the additional methods as `@optional` to the `Game` class as well, then only implement them in my `CutthroatGame` .m file. In this case, the compiler and run-time would be happy.. correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why you got that error is because:
`@property (strong) Game *game;`
The type of game is `Game` not `CutthroatGame`. So when you try to do `_game.opponent2 = [players objectAtIndex:0];` it gives you an error.
You can try this:
`((CutthroatGame *)_game).opponent2 = [players objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: That does seem to work.. but kind of eliminates the whole point of overriding the property. Can`t access methods of `CutthroatGame` with `_game` either. Would I benefit from flipping the `_game` property to be `@property (strong) CutthroatGame *game;` ??? That way I can access the methods and properties of both without having to use the `((CutthroatGame *)...)` solution? If so.. if `CutthroatGame` overrides a method from `Game`, and I am using `_game = [Game...];` would the compiler pick the right method from `Game`, or use the implementation in `CutthroatGame`?

Comment: Actually you cannot change it to `@property (strong) CutthroatGame *game;`. Since if you do so, you cannot assign a `Game` object to _game. The compiler will give you an error here `_game = [[Game alloc] init];`

Comment: @AndrewRobinson Take a minute to think about what you are asking the runtime to do.  You are asking it to believe that it will be a CutThroatGame every time.  It's not CutThroatGame, it is Game.  Because of this, the compiler will only allow methods defined in the Game class (without a cast).  As for overriding, the method called is the method lowest on the inheritance chain (i.e. depends on the type, for CutThroatGame it will be CutThroatGame's methods though)